# How to include a file within preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, include, preg-replace-callback

lets say example.php is

```
echo("123");
```

How can i change regex matched  include rule within this string **"abc{include 'example.php'}def"** with php executed included result. **Result should be "abc123def"**

I wrote this code and works but its not running php code within the included file. So results is "abcecho("123);def", which is not i'm looking for.

```
preg_replace_callback("/\{\s*include\s*'(.*?)\'\s*}/", function($m) { return file_get_contents($m[1]);}, $str);
```

Thanks

Comment: The real question here is: What do you want to do? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: i want to be able to include my php modules with strings retrieved from database

Comment: `file_get_contents` doesn't run scripts, it just returns the contents of the script as a string.

Comment: i know, i just wanted to propose my incomplete answer to explain where i got stucked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functions of output buffering. Then callback function would be:

```
function($m) {
   ob_start();
   include($m[1]);
   $out = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   return $out;
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean to leave the `file_get_contents` call in there?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Mistake of copy/paste :)